# How to get cost accumulation that does NOT take distance between cells into account?

Tags: qgis, raster, arcgis-pro, least-cost, cost-surface

I have performed a cost analysis on a raster, more specifically to obtain a cost accumulation raster, using the tools r.cost in QGIS and cost-distance in ArcGIS Pro.

In these tools, cost between cells is calculated using the formula: ((cost1 + cost2) / 2) * distance

*(In the case of a cell resolution of 1x1 m)*

The cost between two perpendicular cells: (cost1 + cost2) / 2

The cost between two diagonal cells : ((cost1 + cost2) / 2) * 1.414214

However, I would like to obtain a cost accumulation raster, where the distance between diagonal cell centers and perpendicular cell centers is **not** taken into account or different. So the formula for cost is the same in both cases.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can get a cost accumulation raster that does not take into account the distance between two cell centers (or where the distance between the cell centers is considered the same)? I have tried using the Path Distance tool in ArcGIS, where the cost-formula is somewhat changeable but the diagonal distance continues to pose a problem.